# iCloud documents in list view (in browser)

Tags: icloud

When viewing my iCloud documents in a browser window, they are displayed by default in icon view.  There doesn't seem to be an option to view them in list view -- which seems astonishing to me.  Am I just missing it?

(Just to clarify:  I am *not* asking about viewing iCloud documents in a Finder window, or through an iOS app.  I'm talking about viewing iCloud via a web browser, i.e. when logging in to icloud.com.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The iCloud Drive interface does not currently have any settings to change from icon view via the web.

Comment: ....this is nuts, right?

Comment: yes, yes it is.